# DragAndDrop selectedItems of one silverlight Datagrid into another

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

Currently I am using "DataGridDragDropTarget" to Drag a row from one datagrid to another, but a client want to be able to select multiple rows from one datagrid and drop them into another.

I played around a bit but realized "DataGridDragDropTarget" seems to be able to drag and drop single row at a time only.

Is there any alternative way to DragDrop multiple selected rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing Shift key while dragging multiple rows to another datagrid really works for this. But can anyone suggest how can I remove shift key press while moving multiple rows or how to drag while holding CTRL?

Comment: http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-with-silverlight-toolkit-drag-and.html might be helpful