# WPF Drag and Drop Rows from One Datagrid to another Datagrid with has same columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I have requirement where i have drag and drop row from datagrid to another datagrid using WPF application.

Can any one help with a sample code or any links to go through.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done an internet search? LOTS of examples online

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below tutorials for these... There are more examples over the internet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996459.aspx

[DragAndDrop selectedItems of one silverlight Datagrid into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882458/draganddrop-selecteditems-of-one-silverlight-datagrid-into-another)

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=677

http://www.blog.ingenuitynow.net/Silverlight+4+Drag+And+Drop+DataGrids+With+Access+To+The+Data+Being+Dropped.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/36c1160f-c63b-41ca-91f9-a38c934ee83b

Comment: Hi david.. the above links were very usefull from which http://www.blog.ingenuitynow.net/Silverlight+4+Drag+And+Drop+DataGrids+With+Access+To+The+Data+Being+Dropped.aspx link as what i needed but it's in Silverlight i need it in WPF any idea/suggestion how to convert or any other usefull links.